# Codeigniter index.php removal causing 302 found error

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

I have been struggling with this for a while now and have tried everything google has had to offer. My site works fine with the index.php in the url, but for obvious reasons I would like to remove this.

In my .htaccess I have what I've used for most of my site.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and then I am taking the index.php out of my config file

```
$config['index_page'] = ' ';
```

I don't know why, but when I implement the code above some pages work fine, but then others give me a 302 found error at the top of the page, but the rest of the page does load fine and shows all the content.

```
0
Found
The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 25 May 2013 20:50:57 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 3696 Connection: keep-alive Server: Apache/2 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13 Set-Cookie: ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22d2cc22f87cb09c84fbb0600b284633a1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%2268.204.149.255%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A119%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Macintosh%3B+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_8_3%29+AppleWebKit%2F536.29.13+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F6.0.4+Safari%2F536.29.13%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1369515057%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7Db214b062c5b8bae8b9a05249575ec7e6; expires=Sat, 25-May-2013 22:50:57 GMT; path=/
```

Comment: is your CI install in the web root or is it installed within a directory within the webspace?

Comment: also, crank logging within CI up to maximum and see if the logs give anything useful

Comment: I'm working with ipage and have several ci websites going in sub folders off the root. I did move everything to the root to see if that would change anything, but it didnt.

Comment: crank up the logging? I'm sorry I dont think I understand...

Comment: it means, turn it up to log everything

Comment: all right I did, I've never used the error logging before. Will those errors just show up above the content on the website? If so I'm getting nothing back

Comment: there is a log directory within the system directory within CI, check the latest log

Comment: alright, I got back this.....ERROR - 2013-05-24 13:03:03 --> Severity: Notice  --> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string /hermes/bosoraweb033/b1717/ipg.plantationkeyartcorn/plantationkeyartcorner/system/core/Utf8.php 89
ERROR - 2013-05-24 13:03:14 --> Severity: Notice  --> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string /hermes/bosoraweb033/b1717/ipg.plantationkeyartcorn/plantationkeyartcorner/system/core/Utf8.php 89

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, it works for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

`EDIT` BTW, I would replace what I have with every thing you have in your .htaccess file above.

Comment: when I put that I get back...No input file specified any time I move away from the main page.

Comment: See my edit. I would test it by removing everything in your .htaccess file.

Comment: I did that and like I said I'm getting back No Input file specified